# combination of printf and sprintf appends a number to the formatted string

Tags: php, printf

I'm using the following code in PHP to create an anchor link.

```
<?php
                echo printf(
                    '<a href="%s">Modifica</a>',
                    sprintf(
                        '%s&tab=edit-parrocchia&id=%s',
                        menu_page_url( 'holy-mass', false ),
                        $parrocchia->id
                    ));
                ?>
```

What I get is "Modifica128" with Modifica as an anchor that links to the correct resource.
But I can't understand where the number 128 comes from. If I modify the length of the format string, the number changes.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `echo`

printf returns the length of the string printed, so `echo printf($text)` prints both $text and its length.

By the way you don't need to combine `printf` and `sprintf` like this. You can just use `printf`.

```
<?php
printf(
    '<a href="%s&tab=edit-parrocchia&id=%s">Modifica</a>',
    menu_page_url( 'holy-mass', false ),
    $parrocchia->id
));
?>
```